# How do I hide something a turtle drew previously?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I used `turtle.write` to write something on the screen. How do I hide it completely. Not the turtle icon thing, but what's written.

Answer (score 2):

@penny12 use `turtle.clear()` to hide text created with `turtle.write()`